# Best way to send data from ArrayAdapter to MainActivity

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I have an **ArrayAdapter** and while pressing on a button I want to:

- delete some data from my Array which is being held in MainActivity
- delete one line from txt file (FileManager handles deleting but i have to access a file which is private in MainActivity)

How can I send this data?

```
deleteDeckButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //i've done it with DECK_NAMES being static public in 
            //MainActivity and i really dont like this solution
            FileManager deckNamesManager = new FileManager(DECK_NAMES);                 deckNamesManager.deleteLine(manager.getFileName());
            // deck files is static public in MainActivity as well
            deckFiles.remove(getPosition(manager));
            manager.deleteFile();
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
  });
```

That's how I'd like my **MainActivity** to look like:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

static final int DECK_NAME_REQUEST = 1;

private ListView mListView;
private FlashCardsAdapter deckAdapter;
// ATM deckFiles is static public
private ArrayList<FileManager> deckFiles; 
// ATM DECK_NAMES is static public
private File DECK_NAMES; // ATM it's static public
```

EDIT: final version of **ArrayAdapter**

```
public class FlashCardsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<FileManager> {
interface Callback {
    void onFileDeleted(String fileName);
}

private final Callback mCallback;

public FlashCardsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<FileManager> users, final Callback callback) {
    super(context, 0, users);
    mCallback = callback;
}
@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    final FileManager manager = getItem(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_view_item, parent, false);
    }

    TextView mainTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.deck_name_id);

    Button addCardButton = convertView.findViewById(R.id.action_add_card);

    Button deleteDeckButton = convertView.findViewById(R.id.action_delete);

    mainTextView.setText(manager.getFileName());

    mainTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), FlashCardActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("fileName", manager.getFileName());
            getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    addCardButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), AddCardActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("fileName", manager.getFileName());
            getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    deleteDeckButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            manager.deleteFile();
            mCallback.onFileDeleted(manager.getFileName());
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}

}
```

Comment: Use interface to make it...

Comment: Could you please give me some more hints on how this interface should look like, unfortunately I'm still a noobie in java programming and I don't see how using interface here could be helpful?

Comment: Would you post your complete ArrayAdapter code? (imports not needed)

Comment: @elmorabea has already solved, but I will update final version of it(I mean this working one previous one didnt have interface in it and onClick was different as you can see. If something is wrong in here i'd love to hear your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send a callback from your adapter back to your activity.

You adapter would have something like that

```
class Adapter {
        interface Callback {
            void onFileDeleted(String fileName);
        }

        private final Callback callback;

        Adapter(final Callback callback) {
            this.callback = callback;
        }
        ..
        ..
        ..
        deleteDeckButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                FileManager deckNamesManager = new FileManager(DECK_NAMES); //i've done it with DECK_NAMES being static public in MainActivity and i really dont like this solution
                deckNamesManager.deleteLine(manager.getFileName());
                deckFiles.remove(getPosition(manager)); // deck files is static public in MainActivity as well
                manager.deleteFile();
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                callback.onFileDeleted(manager.getFileName());
            }
        });
    }
```

And when you are creating your adapter you would do something like that

```
new Adapter(new Adapter.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFileDeleted(final String fileName) {
                // Do your magic in the activity
            }
        });
```